# javascript string replacement

Tags: javascript

hey guys just a quick one for tonight.

i just want to change a smiley face e.g :-P to a html code like `<span class=surp></span>`
but it comes out with a error which is 
 `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:-(/: Unterminated group`

this is part of my code

```
newmessage = newmessage.replace(/:-(/gi, "<span class=sad></span>");
```

i figured it out and it doesn't like the bracket so is there any other way to do this with the bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regular expression, `(` begins a group - but in your case you want to match the literal `(`, so you need to escapg it with a backslash:

```
newmessage = newmessage.replace(/:-\(/gi, "<span class=sad></span>");
```

Besides that, I would make the `-` optional - most people use `:(` instead of `:-(`:

```
newmessage = newmessage.replace(/:-?\(/gi, "<span class=sad></span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As correctly stated by @ThiefMaster, you need to escape a bracket to use it literally in a regular expression, using the escape character `\`.

But for what you want to do, I think you would be best passing a function as the second argument, so you can replace everything in a single `.replace()` call with a single regex that matches all smileys you want to replace.

Something like this:

```
newmessage = newmessage.replace(/(:-\(|:\(|:-\)|:\)|:-P|:P)/gi, function(match) {
  switch (match.toUpperCase()) {
    case ':-)':
    case ':)':
      return '<span class="happy"></span>';
    case ':-(':
    case ':(':
      return '<span class="sad"></span>';
    case ':-P':
    case ':P':
      return '<span class="surp"></span>';
    default:
      return match;
  }
});
```